# CASE expression in WHERE clause Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have been struggling to figure out how to put a CASE expression in the WHERE clause using PostgreSQL. I need to convert the string to a date (as seen in line 3). This works fine. When I try to pull CURRENT_DATE in the WHERE clause I run into errors. Is this the best way to do this? Any suggestions would be very much welcomed.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN
multi_app_documentation.nsma1_code = 'DATE' THEN TO_DATE(multi_app_documentation.nsma1_ans, 'MMDDYYYY') END AS "Procedure Date",
    ' ' AS "Case Confirmation Number",
    ip_visit_1.ipv1_firstname AS "Patient First", 
    ip_visit_1.ipv1_lastname AS "Patient Last", 
    visit.visit_sex AS "Patient Gender", 
    TO_CHAR(visit.visit_date_of_birth, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "DOB", 
    visit.visit_id AS "Account Number", 
    visit.visit_mr_num AS "MRN",
    ' ' AS "Module",
    ' ' AS "Signed off DT", 
    CASE WHEN
    multi_app_documentation.nsma1_code = 'CRNA' THEN multi_app_documentation.nsma1_ans END AS "Primary CRNA",
    ' ' AS "Secondary CRNA",
    ' ' AS "Primary Anesthesiologist",
' ' AS "Secondary Anesthesiologist",
' ' AS "Canceled Yes/No" 
FROM
    multi_app_documentation
    INNER JOIN ip_visit_1 ON multi_app_documentation.nsma1_patnum = ip_visit_1.ipv1_num
    INNER JOIN visit ON ip_visit_1.ipv1_num = visit.visit_id 
WHERE
CASE
        
        WHEN ( multi_app_documentation.nsma1_code = 'DATE' AND TO_DATE( multi_app_documentation.nsma1_ans, 'MMDDYYYY' ) = CURRENT_DATE END ) 
        AND multi_app_documentation.nsma1_ans IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY
    ip_visit_1.ipv1_lastname ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parentheses are unbalanced.  Also, you don't even need a `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` clause.  Use this version:

```
WHERE
    multi_app_documentation.nsma1_code = 'DATE' AND
    TO_DATE(multi_app_documentation.nsma1_ans, 'MMDDYYYY') = CURRENT_DATE
```

In addition, it is undesirable to store text dates in the `nsma1_ans` column.  It would be better to use a bona-fide date column.  If you *must* store the dates as text, then at least use the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, which then could simply be cast to date using `nsma1_ans::date`.

Comment: I'm still new to Postgresql and learning. I appreciate your help! This works.

Comment: Tim, the problem I have is that the dates aren't always being entered as 01202023. Sometimes they are miskeyed (despite being told not to repeatedly) as 01/20/23 and then my query won't run at all.

Comment: No! the problem is your code does not recognize what appears to be a normal and predictable situation. The correction is to fix the code:  recognize the input and either raise an error or *correct* the entry. Do not just tell the user as **it will never happen** , enforce the requirement or adapt it. Then store it with the proper data type.

Comment: Should I use UPDATE to have it recognize the date field when it is typed in more than one way? For instance, 011202023 and 01/20/23?